# my asynchronous function is showing promise pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, https, youtube-api

I awaited my function at many places but it still showing promise pending.

I am trying to get YouTube video thumbnails by url.

I created a index.js file with this code:

```js
const checkurl = require('./checkurl.js');

console.log(checkurl('https://youtu.be/NbT4NcLkly8'));
```

and the checkurl.js have:

```js
const getvideoid = require('get-video-id');
const https = require('https');
const GOOGLEKEY = process.env['GOOGLEKEY'];

module.exports = async function(url) {
  const urlinfo = getvideoid(url)

  if (urlinfo.service == 'youtube' && urlinfo.id !== undefined) {
    const result = await checkid(urlinfo.id)

    return result
  }

  return false
};

function checkid(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=' + GOOGLEKEY + '&part=snippet&id=' + id

    const req = https.request(url, (res) => {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');

      let responseBody = '';

      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        responseBody += chunk;
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        const data = JSON.parse(responseBody);

        if (data.items[0]) {
          const thumbnail = data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails

          resolve(thumbnail);
        } else {
          resolve(undefined);
        };
      });
    });

    req.on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });

    req.end();
  });
};
```

I awaited all my function which return promise but I am still getting promise pending idk why.

I also tried to resolve the promise in second function but still same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`checkurl` returns a `Promise` because it's an `async` function.

You either need to `await` or `.then` it before you can `console.log` its value.

```js
// in an async function
console.log(await checkurl('https://youtu.be/NbT4NcLkly8'));
```

```js
checkurl('https://youtu.be/NbT4NcLkly8').then(console.log)
```